# How to show font awesome icons (like,views) on css hover overlay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When i hover on top of div tag then am showing one css overlay and i like to add couple of buttons (Like and Share) on top of overlay how can i do that?

this is my code for hover

```
.portfolio-item img {
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.portfolio-item:after {
    content:'\A';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.portfolio-item:hover:after {
    opacity:1;
}

#like {        
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: -35px 0 0 -35px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

javascript used to create div

```
var element = document.createElement("div");
element.setAttribute("id",listItem"+i);
element.setAttribute("class","col-md-4  portfolio-item");
output.appendChild(element);
```

javascript to show overlay icon

```
var ele = document.createElement("div");
ele.setAttribute("id","like");
ele.setAttribute("class","like"+i);

document.getElementById("red"+i).appendChild(ele);
```

html code

```
 <div id="output" class="col-lg-12 container"></div>
```

Now it look like this on hover"

[image]

and am expecting something like this:

[image]

Comment: shouldn't that `ele.setAttribute("id","like");
          ele.setAttribute("class","like"+i);` the other way round as ids need to be unique but not classes:  `ele.setAttribute("class","like");
          ele.setAttribute("id","like"+i);`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a child div inside the main container

```
<div id="output" class="col-lg-12 container">
   <img src="SOMETHING"/>
   <div><i class="fa fa-heart"/><span class="counts">23</span></div>
</div>
```

In css

```
#output img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#output > div{
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    z-index: 10;
}
#output > div:hover{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: how to add number along with heart?

Comment: Is the edit is ok?...This will work out with span tag in it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have setup font awesome properly,

you could do something like this when you are creating the overlay.

```
var ele = document.createElement("div");
    ele.setAttribute("id","like");
    ele.setAttribute("class","like"+i);

var faHeart = document.createElement("div");
    faHeart.setAttribute("class","fa fa-heart-o");

ele.appendChild(faHeart);
```